# Are $E_n$-operads not formal in characteristic not equal to zero?

Tags: homotopy-theory, finite-fields, operads

This is a short question:

Is it just unproven folklore (yet), or is it definitively known that $E_n$-operads are not formal, if the characteristic of the underlying field is not equal to zero?

Comment: I'd say this is a complicated question, since I think you cannot work with chain complexes (for lack of a model structure), so you have to work with modules over the Eilenberg-MacLane commutative ring spectrum of the field.

Comment: I see. Ok then this question needs some elaborate setup like homotopy operads (where formality would be an oo-morphism, not just a zig-zag, like defined in the paper of Dehling&Vallette http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02701)

Comment: Mark, not really, zig-zags are fine.

Comment: I meant that the theory of Dehling&Vallette established a homotopy theory for operads over arbitrary rings. And in that framework zig-zags are 'the same' as actuall oo-morphisms

Comment: Mark, you can choose to work with that paper and with $\infty$-morphisms if you like, but you can avoid all that and use spectra and zig-zags of weak equivalences.

Comment: Not sure what precisely formal means in this context, but if it means any kind of equivalence between an operad and its homology, it is surely false in characteristic p, by the original examples and calculations in iterated loop spaces. The difference gives the Araki-Kudo-Dyer-Lashof operations.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks, such counterexamples are, what I was looking for.

Comment: @Fernando: It is surely a matter of taste. Personally I like those tree-based combinatorics a lot, as I would avoid spectra and all that :-0

Comment: @PeterMay Could you turn your comment into an answer with a bit more fleshed out? Are some of the operations in Cohen-Lada-May not coming from homology classes? (is this the thing that Milgram (or someone else) noticed where there were not enough operations?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, Sean.  I'll write in terms of homology operations.  Let $\mathcal C$ be any $\Sigma$-free operad,
in spaces or in chain complexes, makes no real difference to the answer.  For definiteness, take
chain complexes over a field $K$; $\Sigma$-free means that $\mathcal C(j)$ is a free $K[\Sigma_j]$-module 
for each $j$.  For any $K$-chain complex $X$, $\mathcal C(j)\otimes X^j$ is $K[\Sigma_j]$-chain homotopy equivalent to $\mathcal C(j)\otimes H_*(X)^j$ (exercise or see Lemma 1.1 in http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/10.pdf).   Therefore, if $\mathcal C$ is formal then 
$$  H_*(\mathcal C[j]\otimes_{\Sigma_j} X^j)
\cong H_*(\mathcal C[j])) \otimes_{\Sigma_j} H_*(X)^j $$
so the only homology operations come from  $H_*(\mathcal C[j]))$. But $H_*(\mathcal C[j]))$ is just way too small
if $\mathcal C$ is an $E_n$-operad and $K$ has characteristic $p$. You can see this most obviously if you let $n$ go to $\infty$, when $H_*(\mathcal C(j))$ is zero in positive degrees.  For finite $n$ the algebras over
$H_*(\mathcal C)$ are $n-1$-braid algebras (if $p\neq 2$ or $3$), but the homology of algebras over 
$\mathcal C$, such as $H_*(\Omega^n Y)$ for a space $Y$, have a much richer structure.  A brief discussion of this is given in Section 5 of http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/mayi.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

Paolo Salvatore put a [paper on the arXiv last week (1807.11671)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.11671) proving that $E_2$ is *not* formal over $\mathbb{F}_2$ as a non-symmetric operad (what he calls planar operad), i.e. you cannot find a zigzag of quasi-isomorphisms of operads (not necessarily $\Sigma$-equivariant) between $H_*(E_2; \mathbb{F}_2)$ and $C_*(E_2; \mathbb{F}_2)$. He uses obstruction theory for that.