# Definition of E-infinity operad

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, operads, cohomology-operations

What is the definition of $E_\infty$-operad in the category of chain complexes over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$? J. Smith in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004003 define it for complexes over $\mathbb{Z}$ (Definition 2.24). Sorry but I'm confused with how does the version in
$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ must looks like. Thanks!

Comment: Crosspost: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636588/definition-of-e-infinity-operad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Operads $\mathcal{C}$ can be defined in any symmetric monoidal category, and then
$E_{\infty}$ operads are specified in accordance with the (or a) notion of equivalence 
relevant to that category.  In any category, I prefer to insist that they be $\Sigma$-free, 
in the sense that the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ acts freely on $\mathcal{C(n)}$.

In spaces, it is required that each $\mathcal{C}(n)$ be contractible, so that it is a 
universal cover of the orbit space $\mathcal{C}(n)/\Sigma_n$, which is a $K(\Sigma_n,1)$.
(Some might prefer weakly contractible, which is the same when the spaces of 
the operad are CW homotopy types, as is true in all of the examples I know).
There is not and should not be a canonical example: that would lose the whole
force of the examples, where very different $E_{\infty}$ operads act on different
naturally occurring spaces.

In algebra, we can take our symmetric monoidal category to be
the category of chain complexes of modules over any commutative 
ring $R$.  In that case, it is reasonable to require $\mathcal{C}(n)$ to be free 
(or at least projective) over the group ring $R[\Sigma_n]$.  While 
grading is somewhat negotiable, in homological grading I would
insist that $\mathcal{C}(n)$ is zero in negative degrees and that it be an
$R[\Sigma_n]$-projective resolution of the trivial $\Sigma_n$-module $R$.
Again there are many examples, none thought of as canonical.

This gives the pretty picture that the chain complex with coefficients
in $R$ of an $E_{\infty}$ operad of spaces is an $E_{\infty}$ operad
of $R$-chain complexes, automatically giving many different examples.
There are many other examples that do not arise from spaces.

The $\Sigma$-freeness forces one not to confuse things with $\mathcal{Com}$,
which is not homologically correct or interesting; see
[Are $E_n$-operads not formal in characteristic not equal to zero?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218610/are-e-n-operads-not-formal-in-characteristic-not-equal-to-zero/218886#218886)
which is especially relevant to the case $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ in the question.

Answer (score 8):

There exists several models of $E_{\infty}$-operads. One model which works in chain complexes over any ring is the Barratt-Eccles operad, defined by applying aritywise the normalized chain complex to a simplicial operad introduced by Barratt and Eccles in *On $\Gamma_+$-structures. I. A free group functor for stable homotopy theory* in the study of infinite loop spaces. In each arity $r$, this operad is given by the normalized bar construction on the symmetric group $\Sigma_r$. A nice and detailed exposition of the structure of the Barratt-Eccles operad is written for instance in *Combinatorial operad actions on cochains* by Berger-Fresse and works in particular over fields of positive characteristic.

Comment: Not everybody would consider the Barratt-Eccles operad to be E-infinity.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: What are the reasons for not considering the B-E operad to be E_∞?

Comment: @FernandoMuro As you know, the Barratt-Eccles $\Gamma$-construction provides a simplicial operad, which models infinite loop spaces. So, I suppose with loop at origins of theory, explained in May's 1967 paper on Steenrod operations as well as the book `Geometry of iterated loop spaces' it is an $E_\infty$-operad. One may argue that this does not take place in the category of spaces, but I suppose one can still do with a kind of equivalence beween spaces and simplicial spaces. Furthermore, I think, one can talk about operads in an symm. monoidal category equipped with a model structure...

Comment: ...which I think has been looked at Spitzweck thesis. Even, with that, I think $\Gamma$ stands a chance of being an $E_\infty$-operad. I wonder if this does make sense.

Comment: I just meant it's not cofibrant, which is required by some authors.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Cofibrant in which model structure?  Its underlying symmetric sequence is cofibrant in the projective model structure.

Comment: I don't know any model structure on operads where BE is cofibrant. I'd love to know of one if it happens to exist.